# ReadLine() from two sources simultaneously

Tags: c#, readline

This is my current loop.

```
while(!StartServer.HasExited)
{
    Console.WriteLine(StartServer.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
    StartServer.StandardInput.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

ServerStart is the name of my process. The problem is that the loop waits for input before continuing. Is there a way I can run 2 loops at the same time?
Like this:

```
while(!StartServer.HasExited)
{
    Console.WriteLine(StartServer.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
}
while(!StartServer.HasExited)
{
    StartServer.StandardInput.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: Non-blocking IO and/or Concurrency/Threading are the two options.

Comment: You need to read about [parallel programming.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It's actually a lot harder than it might seem at first, assuming you don't want to be doing mean things like writing out text while the user is half way through inputting a line.  Do you want to do that anyway, wait until they sumbit a line and then print out all of the lines you've received from this other process, do you want to write them out to different places?  Do you want to write out the text to the line below where the user is typing while they're typing?

Comment: (The OP is trying to proxy the server and console stdout/stdin to eachother - such is common in a "chat".)

Comment: I want to receive the output and print it in the console, and send input whenever. At the moment, I receive 1 line when I send 1 line.

BTW I'm a noob.

Comment: @user3873786 So when the user is trying to type in something and the other process has output you just want to stick that output right in the middle of what they were typing?  You really sure about that?

Comment: In response to Servy, those "mean things" shouldn't be an issue. I'll be redirecting the IO from this console application to a windows for application. It's probably not efficient, but I'm only making this thing for fun.

Comment: I'm new to this site, excuse my ignorance.
Edit: By that I mean I'm pretty sure I didn't reply properly.

Comment: @user3873786 It sounds like that forms application should be the one reading and writing to this application's standard input and output, not the other way around.  On a non-console based UI things get way easier as you can have separate UI controls for input and output, removing all of these weird issues that I've brought up.  Just write all output to one place asynchronously and read in from another UI control asynchronously.

Comment: @Servy Getting past step/problem #1 is required to get to step/problem #2. (Using some simple Console positioning would take care of most line-tearing.)

Comment: @user2864740 Try running the following program:  `Task.Run(() => { while (true) { Console.WriteLine("hi"); Thread.Sleep(500); } });while (true) Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: @Servy And? I understand the point that is being made. However, it is silly to address (or focus exclusively on that) that without *first* (or also) answering the question/post. Command-line IRC/talk clients have existed for decades. Also, that problem can be taken care of with the appropriate terminal control on the display and still involves the same *fundamental* problem of handling I/O from multiple sources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

how about something like this

```
Task t1 = null, t2 = null;
while(!StartServer.HasExited)
{
       if (t1 == null || t1.IsCompleted)
           t1= Task.Run(() =>  Console.WriteLine(StartServer.StandardOutput.ReadLine()));
       if (t2 == null || t2.IsCompleted)
           t2 = Task.Run(() => StartServer.StandardInput.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine()));
       Task.WaitAny(new[] { t1, t2 });
}
```

maybe you could even make it smarter to only recycle the task that has finished.

Comment: This is constantly queueing up tons of whichever task isn't finishing.  So, for example, if you recieve 3 lines in a row from the other process you'll have 3 different threads all trying to read a line from the console.  If you write out three lines in a row you'll have three threads all trying to read a line of output from the other process and write them to the console.  And that's not accounting for all sorts of race conditions that can happen, line orders changing because of the lack of synchronization, writing a line at the same time as you're trying to read one, etc.

Comment: Also, you should stop deleting your answers and posting new ones.  Edit your answer if you would like to change it.

Comment: recycled tasks, and sorry i was having double posts so i redid the whole thing

Comment: This works great! Thanks a lot. :D
BTW, minor edit, you made a typo on line 3 ("t 1=" should be "t1 =").

Comment: @user3873786 It works great except for all of the times that it doesn't work correctly...Just because it works *sometimes* doesn't mean it works *all of the time*.

Comment: hey Servy, maybe you could show you how you would implement it.

Comment: @Batavia The problem [needs more defined requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044960/readline-from-two-sources-simultaneously?noredirect=1#comment38955386_25044960) before it can be answerable.  You need to know how it should function in these unusual circumstances in order to write a program that handles it properly.  That said, the real issue here is that [he's trying to solve the wrong problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044960/readline-from-two-sources-simultaneously?noredirect=1#comment38956567_25044960) and should be designing his application differently.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that this is a *very hard problem* to try to solve.  It's not just a one or two line solution to robustly handle all of these unusual cases.